# PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Tags: ssh, openwrt, ssh-keygen

I tried to ssh my router. It first shows:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
0e:82:bb:f1:3a:7f:1f:0d:3f:2d:26:dc:0d:81:61:6c.
Please contact your system administrator.
```

Then I `ssh-keygen -R 192.168.0.1` (router IP). After that, I ssh again. However, after inputing the password, it shows:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

I tried several methods in stackoverflow, but fails. My router is TP-Link N750 with compiled openwrt firmware.

Comment: First verify that it's the only device in network with that ip (check arp entry and verify the mac address, it should be in some tag with the router). Then try to access gui(does that work?), It still not working try to do a factory reset. Might be possible router is out of space.

Comment: Unfortunately I had same problem after flashing "optimized" firmware from https://github.com/shunjou/openwrt-optimized-archer-c2600
resolution was only possible via TFTP recovery

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SSH access in a router is reserved only for [TPLink manufacturer apps](https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/faq/2462/).